# Hibernate creates two primary keys when I only want one

Tags: hibernate, annotations, primary-key, object-persistence

I have a Hibernate class called Expression (simplified here for your viewing pleasure):

```
@Entity
public class Expression {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private String data;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade({CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    private Set<Expression> dependencies;
}
```

This creates two tables, `Expression(id, data)` and `Expression_Expression(expression_id, dependencies_id)`. However, Hibernate sets both the expression_id and dependencies_id columns as the primary key so I can't have a duplicate dependencies_id, which is what I'd like.

For example, if I have three Expressions:

```
Expression x = new Expression("0");
Expression y = new Expression("1");
Expression z = new Expression("x + y");
Set<Expression> tmp = new HashSet<Expression>();
tmp.add(x);
tmp.add(y);
z.setDependencies(tmp);
// Persist x, y, and z.
```

then Hibernate will perform the following:

Insert `x` into the `Expression` table with id = 1 and data = "0"
Insert `y` into the `Expression` table with id = 2 and data = "1"
Insert `z` into the `Expression` table with id = 3 and data = "a + b"
Insert a row into the 'Expression_Expression' table with expression_id = 3 and dependencies_id = 1. (Making `z` a dependent of `x`.)

But when it tries to insert a row into the `Expression_Expression` table with expression_id = 3 and dependencies_id = 2 (making `z` into a dependent of `y`) I get a duplicate entry error.

I'd like to be able to have multiple rows in the `Expression_Expression` table with the same `expression_id` value.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the @ManyToMany relation here